# MS Access: how to create joins to avoid "cannot add record(s); join key of table...not in recordset" error

Tags: microsoft-access

I'm new to MS Access. I have a very simple plant taxonomy database that I am using to try to learn and understand the program. The database has three tables shown below:

[image]

The relationships between these tables is as below:

[image]

Referential integrity is enforced, and related fields are set to cascade updates. I then built the below form using the Form Wizard:

[image]

I chose the below fields in the wizard:

[image]

Perhaps contrary to how some might choose to build such a database, I want to see one record per Species and don't therefore want to use subforms. Hence I chose the below option, and was happy with how the resulting form was laid out.

[image]

When I attempt to add new records via this form, I am able to enter data for Families, but attempting to enter data for Genera or Species gives a "cannot add record(s); join key of table...not in recordset" error.

What have I done wrong in setting up these tables and form?

Answer (score 0):

In order to retain the referential integrity of the database, when adding a record to, say, the `tblSpecies` table, the `GenusID` field must contain an ID which is already present in the `tblGenus` table, else the record in the `tblSpecies` table will be an orphan, thus breaking the referential integrity of the database.

Similarly, when adding records to the `tblGenus` table, the foreign key (`FamilyID`) must correspond to the primary key (`ID`) of a record in the `tblFamily` table.

Since you do not wish to use subforms, you will therefore need to either prepopulate your `tblFamily` & `tblGenus` tables with all of the possible foreign key values, before adding records to your `tblSpecies` table; or, add a button to your form which would open a form referencing the parent tables, allowing the user to add such records on-the-fly.

Comment: That makes sense. However, if the form is populated from top to bottom, in the order presented, then by the time the user gets to the `Species` box, the relevant `FamilyID` and `GenusID` would exist. As an Access neophyte, I had assumed that the software would then be able to associate the user's entry with these relations and update the links accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot modify an SQL inner join - the relationships to the underlying
tables are lost.

You should not be entering data into multiple tables by means of a single form
based on a query.
It's possible to do so in some circumstances, but using a parent form bound
to the referenced table, and within it a subform bound to the referencing table,
is a better solution.

That way each for or subform is bound to one table and so each is updatable
by itself.